# ArgbEvaluator error Android 2.2 and Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-animation

I am coding an android application which has multiple activities and files in `anims` and `drawable` folder I created. Until today, I was running and testing my app in `android 4.2` and it worked well and still works. But today I tried to run it in `android 2.2 and 2.3.3`. But it failed even if the `minSdkVersion` is set as `8 (android 2.2)`., It throws the `exeption` below which I could not find any solution for it. Do you have any solution for this error. I really could not find anything about that on net. Thank you.

**This is where it throw error :**

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void slideUpDown(final View view) {
        final Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.sowc_bottom_up);
        final Animation bottomDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.sowc_bottom_down);
        if (!isPanelShown()) {
            hiddenPanel.startAnimation(bottomUp);
            hiddenPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ObjectAnimator colorFade = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(view, "backgroundColor", new ArgbEvaluator(), Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0), Color.argb(200, 0, 0, 0));
                    colorFade.setDuration(300);
                    colorFade.start();

                }
            }, 300);
        }
        else {
            ObjectAnimator colorFade = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(view, "backgroundColor", new ArgbEvaluator(), Color.argb(200, 0, 0, 0), Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
            colorFade.setDuration(300);
            colorFade.start();
             new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        hiddenPanel.startAnimation(bottomDown);
                         hiddenPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
             }, 200);
        }
    }

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.animation.ArgbEvaluator
at com.inovarge.shoponway.activities.LoginActivity$1.run(LoginActivity.java:64)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: [`ArgbEvaluator` was added in API level 11](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ArgbEvaluator.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ArgbEvaluator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ArgbEvaluator.html) was added in API 11 so it does not exist in earlier SDKs.

Comment: I have background color effect with ObjectAnimator. what do you advice to cover Android 8 and upper version to do so?

Comment: @gabby [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) is a great library for using the Honeycomb animation API on all versions of Android.

Comment: Do you know how to do what I need pointed in my code above with nineoldAndroid?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. NineOldAndroids seems good even if it behaves little bit strange for now :)